# Liferay - Obtain filesize in template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, filesize, liferay-velocity

Is it possible to obtain size of a file from document library in velocity template?

I have a content structure with repetitive files and a very simple template, like below:

```
#foreach($f in $file.siblings)
    <a href="$f.getData()">download</a>
#end
```

The `$f.getType()`, returns value: `document_library`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this information is not directly accessible from the `$f` variable that was injected in your template by Liferay. For Liferay 6.1, the `$f.data` holds the url to the document in the following form:

```
/documents/[group-id]/[folder-id]/[file-name]
```

Luckily, we can hack our way through this and get hold of the actual file by using the service API, which is accessible in Velocity templates thanks to the `$serviceLocator`. For this variable to be available, you must enable it in `portal-ext.properties` by configuring the following property:

```
#
# Input a comma delimited list of variables which are restricted from the
# context in Velocity based Journal templates.
#
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

Once we have this enabled, we can call the right service to retrieve a `FileEntry` object based on the parts in the document URL. And then we have the size as well:

```
#set($url = $f.data)
#set($parts = $stringUtil.split($url, "/"))

#set($group_id = $getterUtil.getLong($parts.get(2)))
#set($folder_id = $getterUtil.getLong($parts.get(3)))
#set($doc_name = $parts.get(4))

#set($docService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppLocalService"))
#set($fileEntry = $docService.getFileEntry($group_id, $folder_id, $doc_name))

The file size is: $fileEntry.size
```

Answer (score 0):

That don't work because you have to escape de url try this.

```
#set($url = $httpUtil.decodeURL($ficheiro.getData(), true))
#set($parts = $stringUtil.split($url, "/"))

#set($group_id = $getterUtil.getLong($parts.get(2)))
#set($folder_id = $getterUtil.getLong($parts.get(3)))
#set($doc_name = $parts.get(4))

#set($docService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppLocalService"))

#set($fileEntry = $docService.getFileEntry($group_id, $folder_id, $doc_name))

The file size is: $fileEntry.size
```